# How do I extract the string that follows another string from multiple files?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I have a lot of files in the folder `filesToCheck`, some examples given below. I need the output `result.txt` as also shown below. I think the regex `CAKE_FROSTING\(\".*\"` is needed somehow for this task, but I am not well versed in bash scripting.
I can use linux bash with any commands that do not require extra installations.

file1.cpp

```
something
CAKE_FROSTING("is.simply.the.best", "[no][matter][what]") { DO(something(0) == 1); }
```

file2.h

```
something else
CAKE_FROSTING(
"is.kinda.neat", 
"[i][agree]") something else
something more
```

file3.cpp

```
hello
```

file4.cpp

```
random_text CAKE_FROSTING("Can be nice") "more random text"

CAKE_CREAM("totally.sucks", "[trust][me]")
```

fileEmpty.h

---

result.txt

```
is.simply.the.best
is.kinda.neat
Can be nice
```

Edit: I tried

```
awk '"CAKE_FROSTING\("{print $2}' filesToCheck/file1.cpp
```

but this gives the wrong output "[no][matter][what]") and only runs on one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Enz 's/.*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n?"([^"]*).*/\1\n/p' /path/to/filesToCheck/*
is.simply.the.best
is.kinda.neat
Can be nice
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I write the output into results.txt? I tried adding > results.txt, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you, the first command runs, but leaves results.txt empty. The second one gives an error: tee: invalid option -- 'E'
Try 'tee --help' for more information. I think tee is picking up the -Enz option, can you tell me how to avoid that?

Comment: Also, do you know how I can get it to work in files with multiple instances of CAKE_FROSTING?

Comment: I opened a new question with my current problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328876/how-do-i-extract-specific-strings-from-multiple-files-and-write-them-to-txt-in

Comment: Okay, @JohnFreeman1212 I will take a look now