# How do I extract specific strings from multiple files and write them to .txt in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I have a lot of files in the folder `filesToCheck`, some examples given below. I need the output `result.txt` as also shown below. I can use linux bash with any commands that do not require extra installations.

The try-out below (with help from stackoverflow) has two problems when I execute it. It only looks for one instance of `CAKE_FROSTING` despite the global flag `g` and the file `result.txt` remains empty despite `> result.txt`.

```
sed -Enz 's/.*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n?"([^"]*).*/\1\n/gp' filesToCheck/* > result.txt
```

What do I need to change?

---

file1.cpp

```
something
CAKE_FROSTING("is.simply.the.best", "[no][matter][what]") { DO(something(0) == 1); }
```

file2.h

```
something else
CAKE_FROSTING(
"is.kinda.neat", 
"[i][agree]") something else
something more
```

file3.cpp

```
random_text CAKE_FROSTING("Can be nice") "more random text"

CAKE_CREAM("totally.sucks", "[trust][me]")
random_text CAKE_FROSTING("Can be very nice") "indeed"
```

---

desiredResult.txt

```
is.simply.the.best
is.kinda.neat
Can be nice
Can be very nice
```

currentResult command line output:

```
is.simply.the.best
is.kinda.neat
Can be nice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the string `CAKE_FROSTING` occurs once per line, you can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -En ':a;N;s/.*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n?"([^"]*).*/\1/p;ba' filesToCheck/*
is.simply.the.best
is.kinda.neat
Can be nice
Can be very nice
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I also managed to write the output to file with > result.txt, it only works for me when there is no preexisting file result.txt, I did not know that.